# Recurrence relation between $a(p^{2n})$'s

Tags: modular-forms

Let $f$ be a Hecke eigenform of weight $k,$ and $a(p^n)$ be the $p^{n}$th Fourier co-efficient of $f$. I need to a determine a recurrence relation (Hecke type) between $s(n)=a(p^{2n})'s$. We can write $1-a(p)X+p^{k-1}X^2=(1-\alpha X)(1-\beta X).$ Doesn't it imply $a(p^n)=\alpha^n+\beta^n ?$ (well, at least for $n\geq 1$). In that case, I am getting a relation like:
$$s(n+1)=a(p^2)s(n)-p^{2(k-1)}s(n-1),$$ this I am getting by simply doing $\alpha^{n+2}+\beta^{n+2}=(\alpha^2+\beta^2)(\alpha^n+\beta^n)-(\alpha\beta)^2(\alpha^{n-2}+\beta^{n-2})$. But someone provided me a counter example with $n=1$ i.e. my derived recurrence relation doesn't correctly compute $a(p^4)$. I am frustrated because, I don't get what's going wrong here. Could anyone please help me out ?

Comment: $a(p^n)$ can be written as a linear combination of $\alpha^n,\beta^n$ but not necessarily their sum. For instance, note that your formula for $n=0$ gives $a(1)=2$, which is wrong assuming your eigenform is normalized. You can find the right coefficients by writing $a(1)=c\alpha^0+d\beta^0,a(p)=c\alpha^1+d\beta^1$ and solving for $c,d$.

Comment: So putting all together $c+d=1, c\alpha+d\beta=\alpha+\beta \implies \alpha(c-1)=\beta(1-d)=\beta c.$ So $c,d's$ are now expressed interms of $\alpha, \beta,$ you mean this ?

Comment: I think this is giving me $a(p^n)=\frac{\alpha^{n+1}-\beta^{n+1}}{\alpha-\beta},$ really I should get this ? It matches with right choice of $a(p)$ and $a(1)$, and everything is determined by them. So shouldn't be wrong,I guess.

Comment: Looks like the correct result to me. Regarding your first reply comment, I assume the flaw in your inductive argument comes from only checking one base case (e.g. $n=1$ which is obvious), which is not sufficient for a recursion like the one defining $a(p^n)$ which depends not on one, but on *two* previous terms.